# How to get the application context from a "non-graphic" class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

I have a "database" class that handles SQLites actions. Part of its constructor is the application's context. So far so good but now, I have a "monitor" class that extends BroadcastReceiver that needs to use this database class and I have no context to build that instance. So there are two alternatives:

1. How can I get the application's context from the "monitor" class or
2. How can I get the application's context from the "database" class

Thanks

Comment: As dave.c says but you may need to cast it back to an application context ie `((MyApplication)context)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't the `onReceive` method of the `BroadcastReceiver` take a `Context` as a parameter?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MyDataBase myDb = new MyDataBase(context);
    ...
}
```

Can't you get the `context` from there?